# Visual Studio App Center extracting your app CorrelationID problem

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-app-center

I want to create a new release for C# WPF App as a `.zip file` on Visual Studio App Center. But, it gives `A problem occurred while extracting your app. (Correlation ID: 342424)`

Am I missing something? Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

[image: upload error]

App Center looks operational:

[image: status]

Comment: I got same issue, did you find any solution for same?

Comment: Hi @JatinPatel Unfortunately no. Did you find one?

Comment: No, still i am not able to identify.

Comment: even i also got this same issue can any one help me in this